# Changing the row reference when dragging down index match formula in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am trying to reference the formula below to pick up the next row when I drag it down my workbook so that the 1 becomes 2, 3, 4 etc. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
=(INDEX(Data!$A:$M,MATCH(1,(Data!$E:$E=$B$1)*(Data!$F:$F=$B$2),0)*1,3))
```

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Do you mean the first 1 in your formula or the second 1?

Comment: The second one, the one that references the row at the end of the formula.

Comment: I’m trying to copy down a product code reference based on two dropdown data validation boxes so I need to match on two criteria and have the data change dynamically based on this.

Comment: I haven't worked out how multiplying the row by 1, 2 etc. is going to be useful. Do you want to get the first, second, third match etc. in your data? As always, showing some sample data and results in your question would be very helpful to people answering.

Comment: Yes, I want the first, second, third match.

Comment: in this example;1 Cats subCats
2 Dogs subDogs
3 Horses subHorses
4 Horses subHorses
5 Dogs subDogs
6 Dogs subDogs
7 Cats subCats
8 Cats subCats
9 Cats subCats
10 Horses subHorses
11 Horses subHorses
12 Cats subCats
13 Cats subCats
I'd want to have a dropdown to select Cats, Horses or Dogs and the list dynamically update based on the selection and ignores anything that is a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Some variation on this formula should do it - the last parameter to Aggregate increases as you pull the formula down so you get the first, second, third...occurrence of the matching row.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$2:C$20)/((E$2:E$20=$B$1)*(F$2:F$20=$B$2)),ROW()-1)),"")
```

[image]